# antlr4 get rule node given a parent and rule class

Tags: antlr4

What is the point of ParserRuleContext's this method

```
<T extends ParserRuleContext>  List<T>
T   getRuleContext(Class<? extends T> ctxType)
```

When I try to get a child context of a parent using this method it always returns null. 
for example

```
parentRuleContext.getRuleContext(ChildOneContext.class,MyParser.Rule_ChildOne)
```

this I assume should return all ChildOneContexts but always returning null.

Am I wrongly using this method and its purpose is something different?  Since there is no documentation on this, not clear about the use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getRuleContext` is supposed to return the ith child (from the variant with the i parameter) or all children of a given class type. If you get back null I'd say you don't have a child of the given type. You can easily check this by examining the `children` member and see if a `ChildOneContext` child exists.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Later I found that this method can only be used to find the children.  What i was looking for is  a method   something like  root.getRuleContextIncludingDecendants(Context.class)

Comment: Ah, I see, a recursive search. Well, the implementation is simple and so should it be for you to write a recursive variant. Btw, if you think answer helped you please accept it. You can also upvote it independently, if you think it's worth it.